# asp.net c# event handler not working second time

Tags: c#, asp.net, eventhandler

I have an asp.net web page that contain panel that will filled up on run time

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    buildStructure(1);
}
```

and this is the method

```
public void buildStructure(int level_id)
{

    pMain.Controls.Clear();
    //Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('" + level_id + "');</script>");

    DataUtility DU = new DataUtility(@"****");
    DataTable dt = DU.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM dbo.PRStructure_Main WHERE level_id = "+level_id);
    int curr_level = 1;
    int curr_child = 1;
    int totalchild = 0;
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Panel pLevel = new Panel();
        pLevel.CssClass = "level";

        Panel pItem = new Panel();
        pItem.CssClass = "item-ceo";

        Label lItem = new Label();
        lItem.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();

        pItem.Controls.Add(lItem);
        pLevel.Controls.Add(pItem);
        pMain.Controls.Add(pLevel);


        Panel pLevelLine = new Panel();
        pLevelLine.CssClass = "level";

        Panel pItemLine = new Panel();
        pItemLine.CssClass = "item-line-ceo";

        Panel pLine = new Panel();
        pLine.CssClass = "horizontal-line";

        pItemLine.Controls.Add(pLine);
        pLevelLine.Controls.Add(pItemLine);
        pMain.Controls.Add(pLevelLine);

        Panel pLevelLine2 = new Panel();
        pLevelLine2.CssClass = "level";

        Panel pLevel2 = new Panel();
        pLevel2.CssClass = "level";

        dt = DU.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM dbo.PRStructure_Main WHERE level_parent = "+(Convert.ToInt32( dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString())));
        lbItem2 = new LinkButton[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Panel pItemLine2 = new Panel();
            Panel pLine2 = new Panel();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                pItemLine2.CssClass = "item-line-level2-first";
                pLine2.CssClass = "horizontal-line2-first";
            }
            else if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                pItemLine2.CssClass = "item-line-level2-last";
                pLine2.CssClass = "horizontal-line2-last";
            }
            else
            {
                pItemLine2.CssClass = "item-line-level2-middle";
                pLine2.CssClass = "horizontal-line2-middle";
            }
            pItemLine2.Controls.Add(pLine2);
            pLevelLine2.Controls.Add(pItemLine2);




            Panel pItem2 = new Panel();
            pItem2.CssClass = "item-level2";

            Panel pItemContent2 = new Panel();
            pItemContent2.CssClass = "item-level2-content";

            lbItem2[i] = new LinkButton();
            lbItem2[i].Text = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();

            int current_level1 = (int)dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0];
            //lbItem2.OnClientClick = "alert('" + current_level1 + "')";
            //lbItem2.Click += new EventHandler((s,e) => evHandler(s,e, current_level1));

            lbItem2[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(delegate(Object o, EventArgs a)
            {
                evHandler(o, a, current_level1);
            });
            pItemContent2.Controls.Add(lbItem2[i]);
            //pLevel.Controls.Add(lbItem);

            DataTable dt2 = DU.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM dbo.PRStructure_Main WHERE level_parent = " + dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
            Panel pMenuLevel = new Panel();
            pMenuLevel.CssClass = "menu-level2";

            //<div class="menu-level2-items"><a href="#">Assets Integrity Management</a></div>


            for (int j = 0; j < dt2.Rows.Count; j++)
            {


                Panel pMenuLevelItems = new Panel();
                pMenuLevelItems.CssClass = "menu-level2-items";

                LinkButton lbMenuItem = new LinkButton();
                lbMenuItem.Text = dt2.Rows[j].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                int current_level2 = (int)dt2.Rows[j].ItemArray[0];

                //lbMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(delegate (Object o, EventArgs ee) { evHandler(s, ee,current_level2)});

                lbMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(delegate (Object o, EventArgs a) 
                    {
                        evHandler(o, a, current_level2);
                    });


                pMenuLevelItems.Controls.Add(lbMenuItem);
                DataTable dt3 = DU.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM dbo.PRStructure_Main WHERE level_parent = " + dt2.Rows[j].ItemArray[0]);


                Panel pSubMenuLevel = new Panel();
                pSubMenuLevel.CssClass = "sub-menu-level2";

                //  <div class="sub-menu-level2-items"><a href="#"> Business Application Section </a></div>
                for (int k = 0; k < dt3.Rows.Count; k++)
                {
                    Panel pSubMenuLevelItems = new Panel();
                    pSubMenuLevelItems.CssClass = "menu-level2-items";

                    LinkButton lbSubMenuItem = new LinkButton();
                    lbSubMenuItem.Text = dt3.Rows[k].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                    int current_level3 = (int)dt3.Rows[k].ItemArray[0];

                    lbMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler((s, e) => evHandler(s, e, current_level3));
                    pSubMenuLevelItems.Controls.Add(lbSubMenuItem);

                    pSubMenuLevel.Controls.Add(pSubMenuLevelItems);
                }

                    pMenuLevelItems.Controls.Add(pSubMenuLevel);

                pMenuLevel.Controls.Add(pMenuLevelItems);

            }

            pItemContent2.Controls.Add(pMenuLevel);

            pItem2.Controls.Add(pItemContent2);
            pLevel2.Controls.Add(pItem2);

        }

        pMain.Controls.Add(pLevelLine2);
        pMain.Controls.Add(pLevel2);
    }

}
```

I have a problem in this section

```
                        lbMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler((s, e) => evHandler(s, e, current_level3));
```

and this is the handler method

```
public void evHandler(Object s,EventArgs e, int someData){

    //Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('" + someData + "');</script>");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),"err_msg","alert('" + someData + "');",
     true);

    buildStructure(someData);
}
```

it work properly first time

but when i click it again its make page load.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `page_load` should be like below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack){
        buildStructure(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried this one but when I click it will disappeare every thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate the exact same controls when posting back. If the page loads with only one control how will it know to raise the click event for a control that doesn't exists.

Edit: 
From what I understand about asp.net page life cycle, you must have the controls created before post back data is restored, that's how page control events fire. So if you have a control say LinkButtonA which was dynamically created on the page and you click on it, for the click event to trigger on the server during the post back, it must be recreated before post back data is restored, therefore try Recreating dynamic controls in Page_Init instead of Page_Load and try to keep the   input to your method "buildStructure" the same. Say if you have called it from the event handler with buildStructure("fifth_level") make sure  that Page_Init does the same buildStructure("fifth_level").

Comment: Correct, when you create your controls dynamically, you need to re-create the exact same controls in the `Page_Init` on the postback.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recommends to create the dynamic controls on preint so you need to create the same controls on preinit like this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{


}
```